# Auto-calculate Excel Formulae Added to a Spreadsheet by an App

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel spreadsheet with calculation options set to Automatic [image: Calculation Options]

However when I add some formulate for example

`=CONCATENATE(“ABC",UNICHAR(8730))`

The formulae do not auto-compute. Even running the manual computation from the menus does not force them to calculate.

The only way to do this is to click in the Cell, and then press Enter which is tedious since I have hundreds of cells per document, and do not want the end users to have to do this.

This does not work in Excel 16 for Mac, Windows Excel 16

**UPDATE 1:** 
Link to sample Excel File https://www.dropbox.com/s/cxdbego1vw1jwln/SampleExcelFileWithErrors.xls?dl=0

Comment: Is your number format "Text" instead of "General"?

Comment: The column is meant to contain text and the format is set to "General"

Comment: Try doing a find and replace swapping "=" for "=". Yes, I know it's the same thing, equal sign for equal sign.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what causes this issue, and I can't replicate it. But the two suggested solutions are:

1. Find and replace - swap "=" for "=". Yes the same thing.
2. Text to columns - click finish right away.